# Is it possible to set resource to all with Kubernetes RBAC?

Tags: api, kubernetes, resources, roles, rbac

Kubernetes’ RBAC can set special resource as [“pod”] or [“cronjob”]. But want to set all resources with the same verbs. Is it the right method? [“”]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to add all resources in RBAC is using ["*"] instead of naming any resources.